# refresh DataContext after use transction

Tags: refresh, datacontext

i want to update 4 table withlinq 2 sql and use transection. aftre cummit all command, the DataContext dont update with new data. but all data save in database.
i need to refresh DataContext after subchange commands. any body can help me?